# Unable to pass data between the pages in angularjs - plunker included

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to pass the data between two pages. I am sending `"hello world"` string from page 1 to page 2 but I am unsuccessful in passing it.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/micM7vlslznEIZXP293Y?p=preview)

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/micM7vlslznEIZXP293Y?p=preview

Comment: may be you should use only one html page with ng-view or ui-view embedded. That's the good way for single page application

Comment: I tried doing that the same way you mentioned. (layout page and ng views) but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Angular was designed for single page applications and doesn't have the ability to pass data between multiple pages in and of itself although there are other non-Angular ways to do this.  Instead, you should use a router such as [`ngRouter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

This will allow you to create deep links in your app and you can use Angular's services and built in functionality to pass data between them.

http://plnkr.co/edit/iruMWNAV4AFdB4tFWzBR

This is only required if you want deep linking, though.  Otherwise you can update your page display by other means like using `ng-if`

Answer (score 1):

Try to save variable in $rootScope

Answer (score 1):

Usually to share data between pages ( im assuming each page has its own controllers)

Two approaches i think of here ,

**Scenario 1:  Two pages with parent child relationship**

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController as prntController">
       <div ng-controller="ChildController as chldController"></div>
</div>
```

In this scenario ChildController has always access data(or Scope) of parent like

```
$scope.parentData = $scope.$parent.parentData;
```

**Scenario 2: Two Pages are independent - Create a Factory to share data ( best approach IMO )**

Best way to share data is to create a factory

```
app.factory('sharedData', function() {
 return {};
}

app.controller('ParentController', function ($scope, sharedData) {
   sharedData.parentData = 'Im parent';
});

 app.controller('ChildController', function ($scope, sharedData) {
  //can access parent data like below
  $scope.data = shareddata.parentData;
});
```